# Is accessing async .Result considered as bad practice?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

If I have following

```
  public async Task<Owner> Get(int carId)
  {
     var car = await myDbContext.Cars.FindAsync(carId);
     return car.Owner;
  }
```

I cannot access the Owner property in the first line cause it's a async call.

If I access it using await `myDbContext.Cars.FindAsync(carId).Result.Owner` does that mean that I'll get stuck in a deadlock sometime or does it have some other side effects?

Comment: Maybe, it depends on the what the context is doing but it is considered bad practice. Why would you not want to use the code you have above?

Comment: Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: if you want one line just simply wrap your async call ... return (await myDbContext.Cars.FindAsync(carId))?.Owner

Comment: What's the return type of `FindAsync(carId)`? Assuming it's a `Task<Car>` then `await myDbContext.Cars.FindAsync(carId).Result.Owner` won't typecheck. If you're asking how to convert your method into a one-liner you can use `return ( await myDbContext.Cars.FindAsync(carId)).Owner;`

Comment: Looks like some clarification is needed. The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. The question in the title has a clear answer. **YES**.  The answer to the question at the bottom of the question is "maybe you'll deadlock, maybe you'll just freeze the UI, or maybe something else bad will happen, or maybe nothing bad will happen; how lucky do you feel today?".  **The correct thing to do to an awaitable is to await it.**

Comment: If you want a one-liner, you can have a one-liner: `public async Task<Owner> GetOwnerAsync(int c) => (await context.Cars.FindAsync(c)).Owner;`, done. `await` is an operator like any other operator; it obeys the rules of parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between your current code and using `.Result` is that, currently, the caller of the `Get(...)` method will be able to continue, until awaiting themselves.

Using `.Result` in the `Get(...)` method will block any caller at that point, until the result is available, and is therefore discouraged.

Comment: That's one reason why it is discouraged, but the more important reason is: **the asynchronous operation that is being synchronously waited might have been scheduled to execute in the future on the thread you just blocked**.  Obviously the thread will then wait forever, as it is sleeping *until it does work in the future and wakes itself up*, which never happens.